# Can you identify the given function?

Tags: functions

I was solving a question where one has to identify the function and then find the summation of that function from $1$ to $n$. However I am not able to identify the given function. 
$$2f(xy)=(f(x))^y+f((y))^x$$
$$f(1)=k{}$$
$$k \neq 1$$

Can anyone identify which function this is.

Comment: One often useful skills in this kind of questions is substitution. For example, substitute $x=1$: $$2f(y)=k^y+f(y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x=1$: $$2f(y)\equiv(f(1))^y+(f(y))^1\equiv k^y+f(y)$$

Regrouping: $$f(y)=k^y$$

Summation, using GP: $$\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)=\sum_{i=1}^nk^i=\frac{k^{n+1}-k}{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The main steps to solve such equations is to substitute one of the variables in order to make it a one-variable equation. Note that we have $f (1)$ with us.

Set $y $ as $1$. We get

$2f(x) = f(x) + k^{x} $,  so that

$f(x) = k^{x} $.

Summing from $1$ to $n $, we get

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  f(x)   =  k+k^{2}+...+k^{n} =  k\frac {k^{n}-1}{k-1} $.

Comment: Oops, someone posted the answer before me. Never mind.